# An invertible matrix is orthogonal if and only if the inverse is equal to the transpose on nonzero elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, orthogonal-matrices, hadamard-product

Let $A$ be an invertible real matrix, and suppose that $(A^{-1})_{i,j} = (A^{T})_{i,j}$ whenever $(A^{T})_{i,j}\ne 0$. Is it true that $A$ is orthogonal?

I found this statement in a paper without proof. The converse is true for obvious reasons.

Trying to write $AA^{-1} =  A^{-1}A= I$ one can find that $A$ has all columns and rows of unitary norm, but not much more. This is sadly not enough to conclude that $A$ is orthogonal (there are explicit counterexamples).
Can you help?

---

For those who asked, notice that for all $i,j$,  $$(A^{-1})_{i,j}(A)_{j,i} = (A^{-1})_{i,j}(A^{T})_{i,j} = (A^{T})^2_{i,j}$$
so
$$1 = (A^{-1}A)_{i,i} = \sum_j (A^{-1})_{i,j}(A)_{j,i} = \sum_j (A^{T})^2_{i,j}$$
meaning that the norm of any column of $A$ is 1. From $AA^{-1}=I$ you get that also the norm of the rows is 1.

Comment: What is the definition of $A_{i,j}?$

Comment: yes, I'll specify better

Comment: Could you include you derivation that each column and row is of unit length?

Comment: @paperskilltrees included more details

Comment: What is the paper that you read?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/333246946917613581/1000715908492296223/unknown.png
@user1551
I guess the author meant that "infinite" is "well-defined"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your claim is false.  Let $$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&-1\\-1&0&-1\\-1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$  Then $A$ is self-adjoint and $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I_3+A$, so that $A^{-1}=A^{\mathsf{T}}$ except where the entries of the latter vanish.

I found this just by asking *Mathematica* to search for a $3\times3$ counterexample; there's no insight to it.  On the other hand, *Mathematica* doesn't think there are any $3\times3$ counterexamples with determinant $1$.  Perhaps you misinterpreted the paper or dropped a condition?

Comment: *"On the other hand, Mathematica doesn't think there are any 3×3 counterexamples with determinant 1."*  Note that a determinant of $\pm 1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for this claim to be true.  This comes from computing $A^TA$ which has all ones on the diagonal hence $\det\big(A^T A\big )\leq 1$ by Hadamard's Determinant Inequality, which is met with equality *iff* $A \in O_n(\mathbb R)$.